# Unable to install IPython in macOS

Tags: python, ipython

I can't install ipython with pip on macOS Sierra.At the end of installation,I have trouble.There is OSError with error number one(Application is not permitted).Is there any problem with pip?I have both python 2 and 3 on my mac.

```
pip install ipython
Collecting ipython
  Using cached ipython-5.4.1-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.4 (from ipython)
  Using cached prompt_toolkit-1.0.14-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting decorator (from ipython)
  Using cached decorator-4.0.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from ipython)
Collecting pickleshare (from ipython)
  Using cached pickleshare-0.7.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pygments (from ipython)
  Using cached Pygments-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pexpect; sys_platform != "win32" (from ipython)
  Using cached pexpect-4.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pathlib2; python_version == "2.7" or python_version == "3.3" (from ipython)
  Using cached pathlib2-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting backports.shutil-get-terminal-size; python_version == "2.7" (from ipython)
  Using cached backports.shutil_get_terminal_size-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting simplegeneric>0.8 (from ipython)
  Using cached simplegeneric-0.8.1.zip
Collecting traitlets>=4.2 (from ipython)
  Using cached traitlets-4.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting appnope; sys_platform == "darwin" (from ipython)
  Using cached appnope-0.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six>=1.9.0 (from prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.4->ipython)
  Using cached six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wcwidth (from prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.4->ipython)
  Using cached wcwidth-0.1.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ptyprocess>=0.5 (from pexpect; sys_platform != "win32"->ipython)
  Using cached ptyprocess-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting scandir; python_version < "3.5" (from pathlib2; python_version == "2.7" or python_version == "3.3"->ipython)
  Using cached scandir-1.5.tar.gz
Collecting enum34; python_version == "2.7" (from traitlets>=4.2->ipython)
  Using cached enum34-1.1.6-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting ipython-genutils (from traitlets>=4.2->ipython)
  Using cached ipython_genutils-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six, wcwidth, prompt-toolkit, decorator, scandir, pathlib2, pickleshare, pygments, ptyprocess, pexpect, backports.shutil-get-terminal-size, simplegeneric, enum34, ipython-genutils, traitlets, appnope, ipython
  Found existing installation: six 1.4.1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (six) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling six-1.4.1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/ws/yr231f3x1n3gh1lt85c0m4fm0000gn/T/pip-ViwdCl-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

Comment: Have you tried with `sudo pip install ipython`?

Comment: `sudo` in front of the command should give you the permissions. If not try installing using anaconda installer or PyCharm ... They do it automatically for you

Comment: I would highly recommend installing [virtualenv](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) and using a virtual environment for all your python development, so that you are not tied to the OS's version.